# Adding zero to a single digit number, Is it possible?

Tags: java

```
public class MultiplicationTable {
public static void main (String[]a){

    int[] x;
    x = new int[10];
    int i;
    int n=0;

    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        n++;
        x[i]=n;
        System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[0] * x[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[1] * x[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[2] * x[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[3] * x[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[4] * x[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[5] * x[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[6] * x[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[7] * x[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[8] * x[i] + " ");

    System.out.println();
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)            
        System.out.print(x[9] * x[i] + " ");


}
}
```

This is a program that will display a Multiplication Table like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20

3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30

4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40

5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50

6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60

7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70

8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80

9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

===============================================================

It is running and correct but I want it to look like this one:

01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10

01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10

02 04 06 08 10 12 14 16 18 20

03 06 09 12 15 18 21 24 27 30

04 08 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40

05 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50

06 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60

07 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70

08 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80

09 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90

10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

===============================================

Is there any way?

Comment: If you ever encounter code duplicated more than, well, say once, **stop** and ask yourself; *what is the easier way*? Now, consider rewriting the above with a[nother] loop construct. "copy'n'paste" is not a language construct/tool.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes you can! You can use `String.format` to add zero padding to your output.

Example:

`String.format("%05d", 2)` would produce `00002`.

Some improvement on the current code:

I'm not sure why you intend to store the numbers inside an array (for practice purpose maybe), but that is not necessary as it goes from 1 to 10 anyway. Though if you want to do that, you don't need both `i` and `n`.

```
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++){
    x[i] = i+1;
    System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
}
```

Secondly, I'm sure you realize that you have a lot of duplicate code, and it's quite sequential. You can do that using 2 nested for loops, instead of having 10 single loops:

```
for (int row = 1; row <= 10; row++) {
    for (int col = 1; col <= 10; col++)
        System.out.print(String.format("%03d", row * col));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven Luu. It helped. :)

Comment: Like the other guys said, your code can use some improvements as well.

Comment: Can you give me some idea how? I'm still newbie in programming.

Comment: If you're new, it's best we not do it for you.  Here's the idea: look at your code and look at the one thing that changes from line to line between your 10 System.out.println statements.  Now, change that into a variable and iterate over it with a loop just like you have done with i in order to print each column.

Comment: Wow! What a short code. Thanks guys, All your answers helped a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
String.format("%01d", x[i]*x[j]); is what you want.
```

If you're familiar with `printf` in C then this will be familiar.  If not, read the java reference on [String.format format strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Also, rather than 10 `System.out.println` statements, you can use a doubly nested loop with two counters.  One to count which row you're in `j` and one for each column `i`.