# Java - Generate Random DOB

Tags: java

I want to generate random DOB for the given range of year. So I tried the below code

```
private static String randomDataOfBirth(int yearStart, int yearEnd)
    {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        int year = randBetween(yearStart, yearEnd);
        gc.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
         int dayOfYear = randBetween(1, gc.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

            gc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear);
            String date = null;
            if(gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) == 0)
            {
                 date = gc.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 1 + "-" + gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }else
            {
                 date = gc.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + gc.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + gc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }
            return date;    
    }

private static int randBetween(int start, int end) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return start + (int)Math.round(Math.random() * (end - start));
    }
```

Main:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String dob = randomDataOfBirth(1899, 1937);
System.out.println(dob);
}
```

I can be able to generate the random DOB. But only for the Month and Day, I want to add a prefix `'0'` for the range from 1 to 9

```
Month - 01, 02, 03 and ... up to 09
Day - 01, 02, 03 and ... up to 09
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279683/adding-zero-to-a-single-digit-number-is-it-possible

Comment: If you must use `GregorianCalendar` (with Java 8 you need not), I think `SimpleDateFormat` is the standard and straightforward answer to your question.

Comment: @nullpointer - Need to add zero in the prefix for month and day, if it is less than 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the desired formatting of you date I see some other problems with your code that I think you would want to address:

- Assuming you want a usual month number, 01 for January through 12 for December, your handling of the month number is not correct. `get(Calendar.MONTH)` gives you a 0-based month: 0 for January through 11 for December. Therefore, your code not only will never give you 12 as month and 1 all too often. It will also give you non-existing dates. I have seen 1905-2-31 and 1929-4-31 (because you get 2 for March, which we interpret as February, etc.).
- Possibly unimportant, your distribution gives each day in a leap year slightly smaller probablity than other days.

If you can, I suggest you use `LocalDate`. The class was introduced in Java 8:

```
private static String randomDataOfBirth(int yearStartInclusive, int yearEndExclusive) {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.ofYearDay(yearStartInclusive, 1);
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.ofYearDay(yearEndExclusive, 1);

    long longDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
    int days = (int) longDays;
    if (days != longDays) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("int overflow; too many years");
    }
    int day = randBetween(0, days);
    LocalDate dateOfBirth = start.plusDays(day);

    return dateOfBirth.toString();
}
```

This gives you evenly distributed, correct dates formatted with 2 digits for month and day-of-month, e.g., `1926-07-05`.

If you want to avoid the overflow check, you may of course rewrite your `randBetween()` to handle `long`s.

If you cannot use Java 8, you can do something similar with `GregorianCalendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Counting the exact number of days from lower to upper bound is complicated, though, so you will probably want to stick to your way of picking the date. `SimpleDateFormat` can still give you correct dates formatted with two digits for month and day. Edit: In your class, declare:

```
static DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Now just substitute your `if`-`else` statement with this:

```
    String date = formatter.format(gc.getTime());
```

If your `randomDataOfBirth()` may be accessed from more than one thread, this won’t work since `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread-safe. If so, each thread should have its own `SimpleDateFormat` instance.

Comment: V.V - Am using java 1.7. So I'm using GregorianCalendar. I posted the code. I just want to append zero for month and day if it is less than 10. Could you provide solution for that

Comment: I have now spelled this out in code in my answer. @Aishu

Comment: It helped :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With Java7 you can try with something like this:

```
public class DobMaker
{

    public String getDOB(int min, int max)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        int year = min + new Random().nextInt(max - min + 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        int day = 1+new Random().nextInt(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, day);
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DobMaker d = new DobMaker();

        System.out.println(d.getDOB(1970, 1980));
        System.out.println(d.getDOB(1970, 1971));
        System.out.println(d.getDOB(2007, 2016));

    }
}
```